# How to plot error bars in python curve fit?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to calculate the error bars and plot them in python. I'm completely beginner in python plotting. Could someone's help how can I do that.
Here is my plot

[image]

Here is my code!! Literally I want the slope and the intercept and fit the deviations to the function. Thanks!!

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

""" Fitting Function"""
def func(x, a, b):
    y = a *np.exp(-1*b/x) 
    return y
data = np.loadtxt("S005_CP_0011_N20.dat", skiprows=0, dtype=np.float128)
xData, yData = np.hsplit(data,2)
x = xData[:,0]
y = yData[:,0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma = None)

fig1= mpl.figure(figsize=(8,6))
mpl.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label="Fit function")
mpl.plot(x, y, 'r.', markersize=10, label="data")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this problem is **calculating the error bars**. **There is no such thing as calculating an error bar**, because an *error bar represents the accuracy of each data point*, and as such, you cannot just use the data you already have to calculate it.

For example, if you were plotting age against height (just an arbitrary example) it would be on you to find out how accurate your measurement of height would be - usually this is done by taking an average of multiple measurements.

The next part is plotting an error bar. With Matplotlib this is quite simple, as you can just use `plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = error_array, fmt = 'o')`, where `error_array` is the array containing the error bar height for each of your points, and `'o'` is just the format of the error bar - in this case a vertical line. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = sorted([35,12,58,43,27,39,68])                              # Age
Y = sorted([1.75, 1.32, 1.65, 1.49, 1.80, 1.67, 1.83])          # Height
error_array = [0.02, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.09, 0.12, 0.01]         # Error bar for height

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.errorbar(X, Y, yerr=error_array)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Oh, one thing I forgot to mention is that you must order your X data, and have your Y data corresponding to that order, so that you have a line graph that makes sense. Do this using the `sorted()` inbuild function in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How do I find out the error from my data set? In your answer, you define the errors randomly right? Is there any method to calculate the errors ?

Comment: There isn't a method to calculate error bars, because they are usually calculated when you are producing the dataset, so you can't calculate an error set just with the x and y data plots you have. See the top of my answer for more clarification.